# How do you label your output of a for loop line by line using numbers?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
sqaure = 1
start = 1443

end = start + 96*3 + 1

for number in range(start, end, 3):
```

I want to make the output look like:

```
1. 1443 
2. 1446
3. 1449
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the first number in your output and then use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) to format the output:

```
for i, number in enumerate(range(start, end, 3), start=1):
    print(f"{i}. {number}")
```

Output:

```
1. 1443
2. 1446
3. 1449
4. 1452
5. 1455
6. 1458
7. 1461
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is set another var (let's say `i`), and increment it every time the loop runs.

```
sqaure = 1
start = 1443

end = start + 96*3 + 1

i = 0

for number in range(start, end, 3):
    i += 1
    print(i, number)
```

You first set i to 0, and every time the loop runs increment it by one, so you get the number of run.